# is it possible to use "git reset hard" after losing access to repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using gitlab. In the middle of project I added another member to project (repo). But now, I don't want him to have access to my source code.

I want to delete the `src` directory and push the changes, then, ask him to pull and then remove him from the repo.

Will he be able to undo the changes using `git reset --hard` or something after loosing access to repo?

Comment: His copy will still contain all data (that is the point of version control) and he can get at it using a reset or by checking out an older commit. You will have to ask him to remove the repo.

Comment: Are you concerned that he might modify your gitlab repo? Or his own local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user has access to the commits he already has on his computer. This is part of the idea of a decentralized version control system.

If you delete code, this will result in a commit representing the "deletion".
He can easily reset to a commit before the deletion. Even if you manipulate history and he pulls these changes, the local repository still has the changes available. If he knows a commit id of before, he can use this to recover the code.

Unless, git runs its garbage collection, then the changes would be gone. By default, this is run every two weeks. Only then, he might loose access.

Instead of asking him to pull, try to ask him to delete his local repository. This would bring you more certainty.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand your plan to cut off his access, but then again if you remove someone from gitlab project they won't be able to access anything from remote (gitlab) but doesn't prevent them to use the pulled files and git history in local folders.

Assuming if you *force push* with commits to overwrite git history till now and he pulls it, then I don't think he can come back from that since he lost all git history.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he has a `local copy` of repository on his machine, so he can do everything on his `local branch` but cannot send these `changes` to your `remote repository`.

So you need to ask him to `delete` the repository from his machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want him to have access to your repo in the remote (gitlab), you can simply remove him from the list of people who had access to the  remote (you can do that by: Admin area < projects < manage access < Users ) , then he wont have acces to your remote anymore,although he can do whatever he want with his local copy except pushing,pulling,fetching...
Hope it helps if i undertand your question well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can if he pulls the whole history. He can still find `src` in the old commits.

If you want him to have access to only the latest revision, you can

1. make an archive of the latest commit and send the archived code to him so that he can create a repository from this code and work on it;
2. or create an orphan branch from the latest commit and give him access to this branch only;
3. or create a new repository in Gitlab for him and push only the orphan branch from the current repository to the new one.